# How to perform Dynamic widget font size depending on the window size

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the font size of the widget depending on the geometry. I have two questions.

1. Using the bind, I tried to change the font size of the button, and it works well with only one button. However, when two buttons were applied, it worked at first but suddenly program fails with the warning sign:

   import traceback
   File "", line 1024, in _find_and_load
   File "", line 170, in **enter**
   File "", line 196, in _get_module_lock
   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import math

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720+400+200') 

lotlist_frame =LabelFrame(root,text="Test")
lotlist_frame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

btn_lotdelete=Button(lotlist_frame,text="Delete",width=10)
btn_lotdelete.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8,relwidth=0.5,relheight=0.2)

btn_query=Button(lotlist_frame,text="Query!",width=10)
btn_query.place(relx=0,rely=0.8,relwidth=0.5,relheight=0.2)

def resize(e):
    font_size = int((math.sqrt(pow(e.width,2)+pow(e.height,2)))/10)
    btn_query.config(font = ("Helvetica", font_size))
    btn_lotdelete.config(font = ("Helvetica", font_size))

root.resizable(True,True) 
root.bind('<Configure>', resize)
root.mainloop()
```

##############################################

2. I also want to change the font size of the LabelFrame txt, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a binding to the root window, that binding will fire for every widget and not just the root window. In the binding you're computing the size of the font based on the size of the widget, but the widget will sometimes be the root window, and sometimes other windows. And each time you change the font it causes the other widgets to change size, creating a whole new batch of `<Configure>` events.

I think the simple solution is to make sure that your `resize` only does work if it catches the event on the root window:

```
def resize(e):
    if e.widget == root:
        ... your code here ...
```

> I also want to change the font size of the LabelFrame txt, but I don't know how to do it.

Assuming you mean the tkinter.LabelFrame, you do it the same way as with other widgets: `lotlist_frame.configure(font=("Helvetica", font_size))`

---

All of that being said, a better solution is to use a font object. With a font object, you can change the size of the object and all widgets that use that font will automatically update.

Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter.font import Font
import math

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720+400+200')

resizable_font = Font(family="Helvetica")

lotlist_frame =LabelFrame(root,text="Test", font=resizable_font)
lotlist_frame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

btn_lotdelete=Button(lotlist_frame,text="Delete",width=10, font=resizable_font)
btn_lotdelete.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.8,relwidth=0.5,relheight=0.2)

btn_query=Button(lotlist_frame,text="Query!",width=10, font=resizable_font)
btn_query.place(relx=0,rely=0.8,relwidth=0.5,relheight=0.2)

def resize(e):
    if e.widget == root:
        font_size = int((math.sqrt(pow(e.width,2)+pow(e.height,2)))/10)
        resizable_font.configure(size=font_size)

root.resizable(True,True)
root.bind('<Configure>', resize)
root.mainloop()
```

This example correctly changes the font of all of the widget, though the end result isn't very good since you use `place`, and because your calculation of the new size isn't particularly accurate. However, it illustrates how you can change the font object and all widgets that use that font will automatically see the changes.